# I need to document R code/console similar to a SAS log

Tags: r

I work for a research department that is tired of paying half a million a year to SAS.  As the only R/SAS dual user in the department, I have been tasked with leading the transition.  Most of our analysts have been good sports about it, going more smoothly than I'd thought.

But we need a way to log our programs for documentation purposes, similar to what we did with SAS.  The logs need to have simple metrics in them, number of observations when merging data, warnings/errors, probably all the output as well.

Some of this stuff is output in the console and I can sink() to save the thing, but there is a lot that isn't output.  We can add extra code to programs to document these things -- nrows() before/after merging, for example --, but I want to make it easier for my analysts.

Can anyone point me in a direction to more easily output a more detailed log from R?  A package or some function I've never heard of?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example of such log file?

Comment: This is an area where R is not so great. If you want to log an interactive session like SAS that is really hard. If you want are willing to run R in batch you can do OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider converting scripts into rmarkdown files. Compiling the rmarkdown files can yield log files which are much more potent than plain text files.

`glimpse()` for the `dplyr()` package is useful to get a quick view on the content of a dataframe. `str()` gives similar output for dataframes and works on other classes too.

```
library(dplyr)
glimpse(mtcars)

Observations: 32
Variables: 11
$ mpg  (dbl) 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 1...
$ cyl  (dbl) 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8...
$ disp (dbl) 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167...
$ hp   (dbl) 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 2...
$ drat (dbl) 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3...
$ wt   (dbl) 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.4...
$ qsec (dbl) 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18....
$ vs   (dbl) 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ am   (dbl) 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ gear (dbl) 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3...
$ carb (dbl) 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2...
```

Comment: I think `summary` has that covered already. I'd be curious to hear about getting the OP's other part -- "number of observations when merging data" -- into logs.

Comment: summary() doesn't give the number of observations. glimpse() and str() do give the number of observations.

Comment: Oh right, good point. Any thoughts on the other part of the question? It's been a while since I used SAS, but I guess the OP means like "100 records matched; 10 records in A unmatched" (such as I see in Stata).

Comment: The describe function from Hmisc package can be used to get a more detailed description of data

Comment: This guy provides a similar feature in demo but couldn't find his code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gw9o41ymPRE

Answer (score 1):

If you run an R script in the command line with `R CMD BATCH` you can save an `Rout` file with the code, plus all the output including warnings, and errors, which essentially the same as a Stata log file, which your coworkers are probably fine with if they like SAS.

You could write wrapper function for things you do a lot and want certain documentation for i.e. merges like you said. So something like:

```
sasMerge <- function(x, y, ...) {
  print(sprintf("The first table has %s rows", nrow(x)))
  print(sprintf("The second table has %s rows", nrow(y)))

  out <- merge(x, y, ...)

  print(sprintf("The merged table has %s rows", nrow(out)))

  return(out)
}
```

A full reproducible example with a log file is here:

```
rFile <- file("test.r")
rCode <- '
sasMerge <- function(x, y, ...) {
  print(sprintf("The first table has %s rows", nrow(x)))
print(sprintf("The second table has %s rows", nrow(y)))

out <- merge(x, y, ...)

print(sprintf("The merged table has %s rows", nrow(out)))

return(out)
}

authors <- data.frame(
  surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
  nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
  deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 4)))
books <- data.frame(
  name = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney",
             "Ripley", "Ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
  title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
            "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
            "LISP-STAT",
            "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
            "Interactive Data Analysis",
            "An Introduction to R"),
  other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
                   "Venables & Smith"))

sasMerge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name")
'

writeLines(rCode,rFile)
close(rFile)

system("R CMD BATCH test.r")
```

If you run this an example merge is run and the log file is saved